# Make IdentityServer coexist with home-grown SSO solution

Tags: single-sign-on, identityserver3

I'm implementing IdentityServer to be our SSO solution across our range of products.  All products will depend on IdentityServer.

One of my public-facing applications has a home-grown SSO solution for customers to use.  Obviously, this is a terrible idea and we need to replace it with something that is a real standard. I want my IdentityServer to be the broker between our apps and our clients. So mycustomer.myapp.com sends users to IdentityServer, and depending on what we have defined for mycustomer, it either uses local auth or SAML or whatever.

That’s a well-supported use case for IdentityServer and works just great.

For the moment, I need IdentityServer to coexist with the old home-grown solution.  Once we have IdentityServer in place, I can start to convert customers over, but I need 6 months or more of overlap.

I need to have a customer post an old-style SSO token (a form post variable containing a key) to mycustomer.myapp.com and have myapp.com tell the identity server to log the user in.  I want this to happen without any user interaction.

I can certainly pass values from the relying party using the ACR collection, but I need to have IdentityServer immediately authenticate the user and send them back to the relying party (hybrid flow).  How do I do this?

I can't be the only person who needs to have a solid, industry standard system coexist with some weird home-grown solution.

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of future generations....

You can read more details in the [Github issue](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2385), but the secret is to authenticate in `PreAuthenticateAsync`, but make sure one sets the AuthenticateResult's IdentityProvider to one that is in the client's list of acceptable identity providers.

If you don't do that, you get a redirect loop.  The log does note the problem, but it lists it as a WARN, not an ERROR.